# Docker: cannot use postgres client connect to database container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have created a docker container. This database container is run successfully. I can connect to this container and see all details of database. Here is some configuration:

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: abc
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: abc
      POSTGRES_DB: database_dev
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
    - postres_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

Here is information I inspect from this running container:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "Ports": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5432"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Networks": {
                "medusa_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "74f7f48596e3",
                        "db"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "d48bbf5453a7c42facda69a8c2c741a20bc18d35238854c00f068bd19119afc4",
                    "EndpointID": "5587658ae084eba71e65fb4712bc75a0ea7c240b600d77d4b4722f5a91818d73",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.5",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                }
            }
```

Based on those information, I try some postgres clients such as PgAdmin4 or Adminer and using those information:

```
host: 172.19.0.5 (get from inspect)
port: 5432          (get from inspect)
user name: abc (get from docker-compose config)
password: abc  (get from docker-compose config)
database name: abc_dev (get from docker-compose config)
```

But all clients cannot connect. I don't know what is it wrong here ? Please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

The IP addresses you get from `inspect` are the addresses in Docker's internal network, not addresses you can see from outside of containers.

Since you're exposing the port in your compose file (the `5432:5432` setting under `ports`), you can simply connect to port `5432` on the host Docker is running the container. If you're trying to connect from the host Docker is on, `localhost:5432` will work.

Comment: I have tried with localhost or 0.0.0.0 before. But I received error something like "connection refuse". If I input ip in inspect, there will be a big waiting time (then fail). That is the main difference.

Comment: Just a note that the  .Ports."5432/tcp".HostIp value is an external address, it's just normally 0.0.0.0 unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự immediate connection refused implies postgres or the proxy is not listening on the port. Check the logs for the `db` container